# Java parallel radix sort using lambda function

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, radix-sort

I'm making a Radix sort using lambda function in java.

The problem I want to resolved is this one :

```
int[] input = ...
...
for(int p : position) {
  //process using input values 
  int[] b = Arrays.stream(input).parallel().map(x -> x >> p & 1 ).toArray();

  ...

  //process which change the place of element i to the place of d[i] 
  int[] output = new int[input.length];
  IntStream.range(0, input.length).forEach(i -> output[d[i]] = input[i]);
  input = output 
}
```

But this code is incompatible with the lambda calculus in java because java required non-final values. 
I have try something like this:

```
for(int p : position) {
  if(p==0){
        int[] tmp = input ; 
  }
  else {
      int[] tmp = output;       
  } 
  int[] b = ...
}
```

But java tell me that output is not initialise or does not exist.

How can I bypass this problem ? 
Should I write the function Myself using FrokJoinPool ?
In that case I have think of creating n ( the size of the input ) functions which place the element of input[i] to a new arrays at the place d[i]. And then launch them using ForkJoinPool.invokeALL() .

Thanks in advance !

### Edit :

I have resolve the problem with the line : 
    int[] tmp = input

Here is all my code, I am creating a lot of Array, Do you think it is a good way of doing the radix sort or is there too many arrays created ?

```
    int[] input = {4,7,2,6,3,5,1,0}
    int cmpt = 0 ; 
    int totalFalses ; 
    final int[] posi =new int[31];
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(posi, i -> i );

    OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(input).parallel().max();    
    int d_max = RadixSort.log2nlz(max.getAsInt());

    for( int p : posi) {
        System.out.println("=========new loop ==========");


        int[] b = Arrays.stream(input).parallel().map(x -> x >> p & 1 ).toArray();

        //take into account the bit. 
        System.out.println("b= " + Arrays.toString(b) );


        //reverse the bit and make a exclusive prefix sum ! 
        int[] e_f = Arrays.stream(input).parallel().map(x -> ~x >> p & 1 ).toArray();
        totalFalses = e_f[e_f.length-1] ;

        //Doing the prefix sum exclusive with a function created. The one from java is inclusive. 
        ParallelPrefixSum PPS = new ParallelPrefixSum(e_f , 0, e_f.length-1,RadixSort.log2nlz(e_f.length-1)) ;
        try {
            PPS.scan();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        totalFalses += e_f[e_f.length-1] ;
        System.out.println("e_f= " + Arrays.toString(e_f) );
        int totalFalsetmp = totalFalses;

        //create and compute t arrays
        int[] t = new int[input.length] ;
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(t, i -> i - e_f[i] + totalFalsetmp ) ; 
        System.out.println("t= " + Arrays.toString(t) );

        //create and compute d arrays
        int[] d = new int[input.length] ;
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(d, i ->  (b[i]==1)?t[i]:e_f[i]) ; 
        System.out.println("d= " + Arrays.toString(d) );    

        //place element in the rigth order
        int[] tmp = input ; 
        int[] output = new int[input.length];
        IntStream.range(0, input.length).forEach(i -> output[d[i]] = tmp[i]);
        input = output ; 

        if(cmpt >= d_max){
          break ; 
        }
        cmpt ++ ; 
    }
```

Comment: What specific variable does Java complain is not final?

Comment: Java complains about the variable input.